# Get latex output of \cite

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Is there a way to get the output of what latex would use to the write the citation in latex? For example, if I'm running bibtex and I want to just get the latex output of what would generate my "references" section.

This example is a little contrived because the bib entries are explicitly formatted, but I hope it helps illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Testing\cite{lamport94}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{lamport94}
    Leslie Lamport,
    \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
    Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
    2nd Edition,
    1994.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Let's suppose, however, that "lamport94" was contained in a .bib file with all the @author, etc... I would then be looking for something to give me "Leslie Lamport, \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}. Addison Wesley, Massachusetts, 2nd Edition, 1994."

I can see some stuff in the .bbl file generated when I run bibtex, but it's not quite what I'm looking for...

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I'm looking for something that would give general output without all of the definitions.
For example, in my .bbl I have something like:

```
[{\citenamefont {Moore}(2006)}]{moore_cramming_2006}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {G.~E.}\ \bibnamefont
  {Moore}},\ }\href {\doibase 10.1109/N-SSC.2006.4785860} {\bibfield  {journal}
  {\bibinfo  {journal} {{IEEE} {Solid-State} Circuits Newsletter}\ }\textbf
  {\bibinfo {volume} {20}},\ \bibinfo {pages} {33} (\bibinfo {year}
  {2006})}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%
```

but it requires a whole slew of definitions from the top of the .bbl file. I'm wondering if there's something that could just be copy+pasted more easily.

Comment: One of the reasons I wanted to do this can be solved by the "bibentry" package, but I'm looking for a more general solution that will just produce the parsed output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt this is possible the way you're looking at it.
bibtex styles are very versatile, and contain a lot of flexibility to tune output, achieve multilinguality purposes etc.
I'd try out one of the "traditional" styles like `plain`, they should be nearer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks! The pointer to using plain was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for!